# Wamp Server3 issues

Tags: wamp, wampserver

My Wamp3 server is running fine. The Icon is Green
But I am not able to access localhost or any virtual host.

Interestingly if I ping the virtual host form Command Promt, I get the response packets fine.

There is no error in the logs.

Can't make out what else I can check.
Just one day back it was running fine.

Comment: Check you firewall. When wampserver first starts it usually causes your firewall to ask if it is allowed access on port 80, but many people dont understand why it shoudl require this and say NO. Apache needs access via port 80 even for `on the single PC` only access

Answer (score -1):

Access localhost with port.

For example localhost:8080